# How to navigate to new widget as a child in widget tree in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-navigation

In the example below when I push new MaterialPageRoute "Child" it is created on the same level as MyApp widget in the Flutter widget tree. I would like to have it as a child of widget MyApp, so MyApp would be a parent of Child widget.

Here is a full code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar:AppBar(),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Center(
            child: Text("This is home"),
          ),
          ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap:true,
          itemCount:10,
          itemBuilder:(context,index){
            return InkWell(
            onTap:(){
              Navigator.of(context)
                  .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Child(index)));
            },
            child:Container(
            height:50,
            width:50,
            child:Text("item $index",style:TextStyle(color:Colors.white))));
          }),
          
        ],
      ),
    ),
    );
  }
}

class Child extends StatelessWidget {
  final int index;
  Child(this.index);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar:AppBar(),
        body: Container(
      child: Text("Child view $index"),
    ));
  }
}
```

I understand it can be done using nested navigation but I am unable to use Navigator.[image: this is the current structure of widget tree]

Comment: Hey, did you find any solution for it? I'm facing the same issue. I don't wanna use Nested Navigator.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to change the `InkWell` widget with `Container` as shown below, because the container overlaps the inkwell behavior, thus no action can be performed:

```
      ListView.builder(shrinkWrap:true, itemCount:10, itemBuilder:(context,index){
        return Container(
          height:50,
          width:50,
          child: InkWell(
            child: Text("item $index",style:TextStyle(color:Colors.white)),
            onTap:(){
             Navigator.of(context)
              .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Child(index)));
          })),
      })
```

Comment: my code is working fine. I just wanted that navigation to new screen (Child) should be as a child of MyApp. And right now it is on the same level as of MyApp.

Comment: Apparently, this existing code should work properly. Would you mind providing the result screenshots so that I can help you out ?

Comment: I have added the current structure of widget tree. In this you can see that Child widget is the sibling of Scaffold and I want Child widget to be child of Scaffold.